# Foreach inside foreach issiue

Tags: php

Have multiselect and I need to add selected for specific option.

have $servicesCat array with id's - It can be 1 / 2 / 5 and so on.
and have $servicesCategories with all categories.

```
foreach($servicesCat as $cat) {   
  foreach($servicesCategories as $onCategory) {
    if($cat == $onCategory->id) {
        echo '<option value="'.$onCategory->name.'" selected>'.$onCategory->id.'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$onCategory->id.'">'.$onCategory->name.'</option>';
    }
  }
}
```

but it return 2 time same option, there can be the problem ?

Comment: you only need one `foreach` loop. search `in_array`, it may help you with the problem that you want solve.

Comment: What is your goal? It seems $servicesCat is always a part of $servicesCategories. Maybe in_array() inside only 1 loop can help you

Comment: @Federkun thanks, problem solved :)

Comment: @Federkun, please insert your advice as an answer and ask Mantas to accept it, as adviced [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)